# How to fill a column of formulas with variables rows in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-formula

I'm looking to fill a specific column with a formula with variable rows, using a for loop. I'm always getting a range global failure problem. If anyone could help me out, that'd be great, thanks!

```
For i = 3 To lastrow
    With Sheets(1)
        .Range("H:" & i).Formula = "=SUM(C" & i & ";E" & i & ";G" & i &")"
    End With
Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove the colon after "H" (H3 instead of H:3 is correct syntax)
- In VBA, formulae use comma not semi-colon, whatever your local
  settings (or use `FormulaLocal`)
- You can avoid the loop

---

```
Sheets(1).Range("H3:H" & lastrow).Formula = "=SUM(C3,E3,G3)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! Exactly what I was looking for. I did not think that after row 4, it would fill according the matching row.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `.FillDown` which will do what you need and avoid `loop` which can take more time and use more CPU

```
Range("H3").Value="=SUM(C3,E3,G3)"
Range("H3:H" & lastrow).FillDown
```

Output **Before**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I'm understanding correctly, .filldown would be the equivalent of the double-click on the bottom right square in the cell?

Comment: @Skepie Sure it does and i guess it is the proper way to do what you need